# Get the title of images and into tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a photo gallery with one large image and a row of smaller images below that large image. When clicking on one of the smaller images in the row, it shows up as the larger image in `#container`. And I'm trying to make a tooltip with the title of the image in it, but it doesn't work well. I keep seeing the title of the first image ('bloemtje op z'n neus) in the tooltip, also when I clicked one of the other images and hovered over it. Probs something simple, but I can't work it out. Tried it with `$('#strip img').attr('title')`. Here's the whole code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#strip').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var bron = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#container img').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', bron).fadeIn('fast')
    });
  });


  $('#container img').on('mouseenter', function(e) {

    var div = $('#strip img').attr('title') //how to display title of each image in tooltip?
    var position = {
      'top': (e.pageY - 10) + 'px',
      'left': (e.pageX + 15) + 'px'
    }

    $('<div class="tooltip"></div>')
      .text(div)
      .appendTo('body')
      .css(position)
      .fadeIn();
  });




  $('#container img').on('mouseleave', function(e) {

    $('.tooltip').remove()


  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 435px;
}

#container img {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

#strip {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#strip img {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF"></div><br>
<div id="strip">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF" id="1" title="Bloemetje op z'n neus" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/00FF00" id="2" title="Een stel hondjes" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000" id="3" title="Puppy's" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF00FF" id="4" title="Nog een" />
</div>
```

So I want to see the title of the image in the tooltip, but no matter which image is clicked, I keep seeing the title of the first image in the tooltip

Comment: For your tooltip, I would recommend creating the tooltip div once on document.ready and just updating the text and position.  It would perform better than removing and re-adding it to the DOM each time.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you invoke `function()`, the value represented by `this` changes...

So it might be useful to cache the event data itself `function (e)`  or it might make more sense to  create an extra reference to the original `this` by invoking `var self = this;` both options are as follows:

```
//cache the event object 
$('#strip').on('click', 'img', function (e){

    var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
    var bron = $target.attr('src'));
      $('#container img').fadeOut('fast', function (){
        // this is no longer the (this) that was in the enclosing function
        $target.attr('src', bron).fadeIn('fast')  // maintain the context
      });
 });
```

Or it might make more sense to just lock the context in like this:

```
// cache reference to the original 'this'
$('#strip').on('click', 'img', function (){
    var self = this; // remember who this is always.
    var bron = $(self).attr('src');
    $('#container img').fadeOut('fast', function (){
    // this is no longer the (this) that was in the enclosing function
        $(self).attr('src', bron).fadeIn('fast') 
     });
});
```

Also close the image tag:

```
<div id="container">**<img src="Images/1.jpg">**</div><br>
```

You should also be aware that `$('#container img')` will select EVERY img tag inside #container. You might want to specify which image exactly, maybe by giving it a unique id.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Tried your code, but it doesn't work, the image is not even showing up in #container. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of achieving what you want. One of those is using the id attribute of the images in the strip.

I've altered your code with:

1. let activeId = 1 - setting a variable which will point to the strip element which is currently shown in the container.
2. var div = $(`#${activeId}`).attr('title') - using the id of the image in the strip as a selector when showing the title on mouseenter.
3. activeId = $(this).attr('id') - updating the `activeId` when changing the image in the container.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  let activeId = 1;
  $('#strip').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var bron = $(this).attr('src');
    activeId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#container img').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', bron).fadeIn('fast')
    });
  });


  $('#container img').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    var div = $(`#${activeId}`).attr('title') //how to display title of each image in tooltip?
    var position = {
      'top': (e.pageY - 10) + 'px',
      'left': (e.pageX + 15) + 'px'
    }
    $('<div class="tooltip"></div>')
      .text(div)
      .appendTo('body')
      .css(position)
      .fadeIn();
  });

  $('#container img').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.tooltip').remove()
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 435px;
}

#container img {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

#strip {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#strip img {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF" /></div><br>
<div id="strip">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF" id="1" title="Bloemetje op z'n neus" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/00FF00" id="2" title="Een stel hondjes" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000" id="3" title="Puppy's" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF00FF" id="4" title="Nog een" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271589/suggested-edit-replacing-jsfiddle-with-stack-snippet-what-to-do

Comment: Message to Goran: First, Thanks for your contributions. Now, when editing posts: Embedding code from external sites such as pastebin, and turning them into snippets is Great! However, Do NOT DELETE the Poster's link. OP is allowed to include an external link. Some users like to use the online version where they can save the code to their own profile, also they can edit and experiment with the code in ways they cannot do on SO. When embedding, just be sure you also keep their link as well. Thanks!!  (I'll delete this comment once it's been read/acknowledged, as it does not pertain to this post)

Comment: Understood and totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

you missed 2 thing to write in your code

You have to copy `title` attribute also otherwise you won't get title of selected image.

```
  $('#strip').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var bron = $(this).attr('src');
    var title = $(this).attr('title'); // you have to copy title from newly selected image
    $('#container img').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(this).attr('title', title); // adding new title
    $(this).attr('src', bron).fadeIn('fast');
  });
```

Use `this` because **this** keyword will refer to current image of container

```
$('#container img').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var div = $(this).attr('title') //use this because it will point to current image present in container
  var position = {
  'top': (e.pageY - 10) + 'px',
  'left': (e.pageX + 15) + 'px'
}

$('<div class="tooltip"></div>')
  .text(div)
  .appendTo('body')
  .css(position)
  .fadeIn();
});
```

You can check working code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh64m5bp/1/)